# Login on empty fields is successfull

Tags: php

Im slowly getting insane. This time i want that it isnt possible to klick the login in button and get ridirected without typed in a username or a password.

I tryed this:

[Redirect after login example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828461/form-submits-even-when-all-fields-arent-filled-out)

[Ridrect after login example 2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Until i ended up with my written code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require('../includes/connect_to_db.php'); 

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (empty($_POST['username'])||
   empty($_POST['password'])){
    $fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }   

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header("Location:Loginpage.php");

}else{
$fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}

?>
```

When i type anything in the login form its says :"Invalid Login Credentials" but when i let them empty and just klick on "Login" he redirect to the shown page. I lose my mind i cant find the damn mistake i made.

Comment: YOu can do this by javascript...

Comment: Whats the link between your second redirect attempt and the PHP developers manual?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable for a sql injection. [What is a SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: Why don't you check for `strlen($_POST['username']) > 0`?

Comment: I would highly suggest investing your time learning how to use PDO within your PHP applications, I find it much easier to use.

Comment: Does it just seem like you store the raw user passwords in the database, or do you really do that?  Because you definitely should not.

Comment: Im just learning so this is nothing for work or something like that...

Comment: It's nice you're trying to learn how to do a login page, but you should first learn about good programming practices and security precautions.. Your code is extremely vulnerable and you'd lose any court trial if someone got damaged because of your site. If you're learning, do it properly so you don't learn bad habits. This is bad on too many levels and I mean this to protect you, not to bring you down. Be responsible as a developer, you'll be doing yourself a favor.

Comment: Maybe i could use something from wordpress or joomla as a loginscript/ form? Would that be save? And if i am good enough i could write my own login script.@walther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']) and $_POST['username']!='' and $_POST['password']!=''){
```

Why don't you try something like this.

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])` does the same, but is more readable and shorter

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user's entry is empty or not by doing one of the following:

**Method One**

```
if(strlen($_POST['username']) > 0){
    //Then user's input is not empty
}
```

**Method Two**

```
if(empty($_POST['username']) == true){
    //Then user's input is not empty
}
```

**Method Three**

```
if($_POST['username'] !== ""){
    //Then user's input is not empty
}
```

In my own PHP applications I'd use both method one and two.

Comment: `if(empty($_POST['username']) == true){` I guess you wanted to use `!==` not `==`. Also since the return type is boolean you could just use `if(!empty($_POST['abc']){`

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Thanks for telling me, and I've found that using the empty function with just `!` caused issues.

Answer (score 0):

you should check that the inputs are not empty first :

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) )
```

or as pr1nc3 answer , something like :

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['username']!='' && $_POST['password']!=''){
```

also check the variable $result by `var_dump($result);`
to check the query results

because in your case it will create the session anyways as long as there are results from the query.